# Missing function in activex control

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I've been using visual studio 2015 to create an MFC application that plots data from a DAQ card.
The DAQ card comes with Activex controls to achieve this and sample programs.

The problems is that after adding the control and adding member variable, the generated .h and .cpp files don't contain declarations or definitions for majority of the functions listed in the relevant documentation.
Could this be due to them being created for visual studio 6 and not being fully compatible?

Is there some way to view the code and manually define the functions with only the .ocx file? (I'm trying to get in contact with adlink but I am skeptical about getting a reply.)
Would using visual studio 6 possible solve the issues?

Furthermore if I open the sample program for a different DAQ card (there is no vc++ sample for my card only vb which I cannot open) all functions are present but if I open a new project and add the same control myself it is also missing functions just like the one for my particular card.

The Card is an Adlink DAQ-2006 using the D2k-OCX drivers for the controls.

Comment: No idea about the card or any specifics, but... `The DAQ card comes with Activex controls` vs. `after adding the control` - yours is a singular. Perhaps you need to "add" more than one control to access the full functionality. Since you have that other sample program that "sees" all the functions, a good starting point would be to compare what their code is referencing and using. Those functions that their code can "see" but yours doesn't must come from somewhere, otherwise the sample wouldn't compile. Track down where they are coming from i.e. which header or #import declares them.

Comment: The sample that compiles is for a different card, I've since found out the manufacturer no longer maintains the ActiveX control for my card. Thanks for taking the time to answer though!

Comment: COM uses type libraries to represent the metadata for interfaces and their methods, arguments, and so-on.  It is the type library that allows .NET to interact with COM objects and understand how to marshall data types back and forth between .NET and COM.  The [`#import` directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) is how you obtain C++ declarations for the metadata in a COM type library.  An ActiveX control either distributes a separate type library or embeds the type library in the ActiveX control itself as a resource.  Try importing the OCX file for your control.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. The 2 files generated were filled with errors which I'm assuming the the root of my problems. I've been able to locate the functions i was trying to use and I plan to add them to my own .h and .cpp files. I'm not sure if it will work but fingers crossed.
Thank you very very much.